# Why is Xamarin Debugger skipping breakpoints/code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android

For some reason, my Xamarin debugger is skipping breakpoints.

Here I have set a breakpoint at line 50. Whether I hit continue to the next breakpoint or step to the next line, the debugger skips to line 54.

[image]

[image]

`x` doesn't exist to the watch list either, as if it never existed.

I've never had an issue like this with Xamarin, but recently I updated to VS 2017, could that be the culprit? I have tried reinstalling both VS and xamarin, trying VS 2015 again, cleaning the solution, modifying various debugging parameters, but nothing has worked. I am compiling with full debug symbols. as well.

Comment: The value of `x` after line 53 can be deduced at compile time; lines 51-53 are therefore probably optimized out.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case because I can replace those lines with other code, relevant to the other lines, and it still will be skipped. Plus, I compile debug without optimizations

Comment: @Rishub Nagpal, If you disable all breakpoints, and then just add one at line 51, and then debug it directly, how about the result? If you still get the same issue(Breakpoint was not hit), One possible reason is that your project was not updated, or the code was not really called by your app.

Comment: Yea, the breakpoint isn't hit. I suspect the code isn't being generated for some reason

Comment: @Rishub Nagpal, If you just build your app, whether you get any warning or error messages in the output window? Not debug your app, whether you could get the changes in your UI if you just run your app using "start without debugging". I feel that the code was not called in your side. For example, if you just comment out line line 51 -53, and then run your app, whether it still run the normally as the previous one with them? Or you could add debugging output messages with custom code between line 51 and line 53 like System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("xxxx") , visit the result if you debug it.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT See my answer posted below

Comment: @Rishub Nagpal, Thanks for sharing your solution, you could mark it as the answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by enabling "Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)" by right clicking on my Xamarin project Properties -> Android Options.

Any thoughts on why this option worked?

Comment: Maybe it got certain deployment issue in debugging mode or others, you could visit the detailed output window and find more useful information with/without that option. Anyway, glad to know that you have resolved this issue, so you could mark it as the answer later. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do this: "tools -> options - > debugging -> general" and untick "Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)"

Comment: Makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: If you have a web.config or app.config check that debug = true. Also are you sure you're running in debug mode and not in release mode

Comment: Just double checked. I'm running in debug mode. I'm able to debug everything, but if I add code it doesn't get compiled

Comment: Try closing your solution. Open the .csproj in a text-editor like notepad or whatever you use and nder the PropertyGroup for the "Debug|AnyCPU" configuration, change the DebugType to portable. Delete all bin/obj/debug folders and reopen, clean, rebuild.

Comment: It should look like this <DebugType>Portable</DebugType>

Answer (score -1):

That happens sometimes to me too. The thing with Xamarin is that it can get pretty buggy for no apparent reason. What I suggest is to try closing you IDE and re-opening it. If that doesn't work, try clicking on the `Build` -> `Clean Solution` button and then on `Build Solution` to see if it helped.

Comment: This is exactly what i found to be the correct answer.. after restarting debugging goes back to normal... dammit!